# Create a 2D image as a SCNNode in scene kit ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scnnode

I am trying to create an SCNNode in scene kit based on a 2D jpg image. This image is to be placed in another 3D SCNNode. I have tried using .background.contents on my scene but this is not what i'm looking for. Any idea of how i can do that? Thanks!

This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!
```

in the viewDidLoad method:

```
let scene = SCNScene()

sceneView.scene = scene
```

in viewWillAppear:

```
let ship = SpaceShip()
ship.loadModal()
ship.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, Double(-1.5))
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ship)
```

this is the class Spaceship:

```
class SpaceShip: SCNNode {

func loadModal(){
    let virtualObjectScene = SCNScene(named: "ship.scn")!
    let wrapperNode = SCNNode()

    for child in virtualObjectScene.rootNode.childNodes{
        wrapperNode.addChildNode(child)
        }

    self.addChildNode(wrapperNode)
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be as easy as just to set an image to the material of a geometry object.

Comment: Can you provide me with an example pls? Thanks!

Comment: If this question is about "I don't even know where to start", my answer is No.  If it's just the matter of helping you with a couple of lines, show your work.

Comment: Check my edited answer. I just want to place a 2D image on top of that ship...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it from the inspector. On any 3d object just go to the material properties and then change the diffuse property to an image, simple as that

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to find the material properties, how do u do this? sry im new to AR

Answer (score 1):

It work for me

```
let node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 0.01))
node.geometry?.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = color
node.physicsBody? = .static()
node.name = name
node.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = MaskNum.barrier.rawValue
node.geometry?.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "Circle")
node.position = SCNVector3(0.0, 0.0, -5.0)
sceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(node)
```

Comment: In iOS 11.2 there is a image rendering problem with this solution (imge is shown as black and red colors only), have you faced like this problem?